# Dynamic changing message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a php array.
I want to make a dynamic changing message (without reload a page) that will change every 10 seconds. 
For example:

```
arr[0] = "abc";

arr[1] = "def";

arr[2] = "ghi";

arr[3] = "jkl";
```

And I want to make a script using AJAX or jquery that prints different string in the array every 10 seconds (print in a div).
My knowledge in AJAX and jquery is very small and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: where do you want to print message? in console or div?

Comment: I want to print the message in a div.

Comment: make a function which makes an ajax call and call it every 10 sec..have a look at `setInterval()`

Comment: "*I want to make a dynamic changing message*" - and where did you get stuck with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You can use `setInterval` and set its iterval period to 10000 ms. select message from array and put it in div's html.

```
var arr = {"abc","def","ghi","jkl"};
$(function(){
  var i = 0;
  var len = arr.length;
  setInterval(function(){
   //assuming div1 is the id of div for message
   $('#div1').html(arr[i]);
   i++;
   //reset array index if last element accessed
   if(i==len)
      i = 0;
  }, 10000);
}):
```